# Какой код лучше использовать, чтобы отлавливать ошибки MySQL?

Tags: mysqli, php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой код лучше использовать, чтобы отлавливать ошибки MySQL?

Такой:

```
mysqli_query($link, $query) or die(mysqli_error() .$query);
```

Или вот такой:

```
mysqli_query($link, $query) or trigger_error(mysqli_error() .$query);
```

И почему один лучше другого?

Comment: Можете предложить альтернативный, правильный, вариант обработки ошибок MySQL?

Comment: Какой из способов применить - зависит от ваших нужд. Первый способ остановит выполнение скрипта и выведет результат на страницу. Для домашней страницы вполне себе.

Второй вариант, насколько я знаю, не останавливает выполнение скрипта. И если дальше есть код, который зависит от этой выборки, то результат может быть странным (если там нет дополнительных проверок).

Хорошо в случае возникновения ошибки просто выводить пользователю сообщение "что то произошло", а в серверном логе все детально записывать.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, чтобы писать все в лог, достаточно в файле php.ini прописать log_errors = On?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Второй (но ниже будет третий). Ошибки можно отлавливать, и когда вы выйдете в продакшен, будет лучше показывать пользователю смешную записку "ой, что-то сломалось", а всю инфу писать в лог, отловив эту самую ошибку. Для установки обработчика нужно воспользоваться функцией [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.set-error-handler.php).
Однако, есть еще более удобный способ организовать работу с ошибками: исключения.

```
class MysqlConnection extends AbstractDbConnection {
    public function connect()
    {
        $this->_connection = mysql_connect(траляля);
        if ($this->connection === false) {
            throw new DbConnectionException('Connect failed'); // здесь мы выбрасываем исключение, фактически, сообщаем движку об ошибке
        }
    }
}
```

после этого можно в любом месте сделать так:

```
try { // это - начало потенциально небезопасного блока, здесь мы можем словить и обработать все исключения или только те, которые нас интересуют, отправив остальные на более высокие уровни
    $db = new MysqlConnection();
    $db->connect();
}
catch (DbConnectionException $e) { // ловим любую ошибку, связанную с БД
    // база отвалилась, делаем последние попытки спасти ситуацию
    $this->render('шаблонище', array('message' => 'Что-то пошло не так: попробуйте обновить страницу'));
}
catch (Exception $e) { // ловим любое исключение, отнаследованное от базового класса - так мы сможем быть уверены, что пользователь получит красивую страницу 500. Впрочем, в случае с пхп мы уверены быть не можем.
    // Случилось что-то НЕВЕРОЯТНОЕ и ВСЕОБЪЕМЛЮЩЕЕ. Это НЕВЕРОЯТНОЕ обязательно должно попасть в лог, а пользователь об этом должен не узнать
    App::log($e->getMessage());
    $this->render('sorry, so sorry');
}
```